# Is it possible to split a command in tmux.conf across multiple lines?

Tags: debian, shell, terminal, tmux

When using the Tmux's `if-shell` command in `tmux.conf`, I end up with really long commands, like the one below for integrating Tmux with the system's clipboard on macOS and Linux:

```
if-shell "[[ $(uname -s) = Linux ]]" "bind -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel \"pbcopy\"" "bind -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel \"xclip -in -selection clipboard\""
```

Is it possible to write commands in `tmux.conf` over multiple lines? I've attempted using `\` to span multiple lines, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to `man tmux`:

> Each command is terminated by a newline or a semicolon (;).

Thus it may seem that it's not to insert a newline in a command.

However, command arguments may contain contain newlines, which can be used to span a command over multiple lines:

`' ... \` or `" ... \`:

> ```
>  If the last character of a line is \, the line is joined with the following line (the \ and the newline are completely removed).
> ```

(`{ ... }`):

> ```
>  Braces are similar to single quotes in that the text inside is taken literally without any replacements but this also includes line continuation.
> ```

Example:

```
if-shell '[[ $(uname -s) = Linux ]]' { 
   bind -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -in -selection clipboard" 
} { 
   bind -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "pbcopy" 
}
```